# Clustered Quartz Scheduler not firing correctly? 

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using Spring 2.5 and Quartz Scheduler 1.8.6 in a clustered configuration. This job synchronizes two databases. I have the following configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" id="quartzScheduler" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean" id="someCronTrigger">
                <property name="jobDetail" ref="myQuartzJobDetail"/>
                <property name="cronExpression" value="${cronExpression}"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyBatchScheduler</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">1</prop>
            <!-- Don't set thread priority for now -->
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">30000</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">5000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

With the property of `cronExpression` set to:

```
cronExpression=0 * * * * ?
```

i.e. I want it to run every minute. I have two machines running this job with **exact same configuration**. I see this result:

```
Machine 1                                                   Machine 2
2012-03-13 09:47:00,009 INFO  Starting synchronization...   2012-03-13 09:46:00,041 INFO  Starting synchronization...
2012-03-13 09:54:00,010 INFO  Starting synchronization...   2012-03-13 09:51:00,041 INFO  Starting synchronization...
2012-03-13 10:00:00,010 INFO  Starting synchronization...   2012-03-13 09:57:00,042 INFO  Starting synchronization...
2012-03-13 10:02:00,007 INFO  Starting synchronization...   2012-03-13 09:59:00,042 INFO  Starting synchronization...
```

I am at a loss for why these two apps aren't firing every minute as they should be. For example, from the two logs above, the job doesn't fire at 9:48, 9:49, 9:50, 9:52, 9:53, etc. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

So as I said in a comment below, my problem was that there was a stray process which I wasn't looking for which was consuming some of the triggers each minute. I killed that stray process and then it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any control over which server runs the job, but you are guaranteed that it will run exactly once on one or another machine. Note that if the system time is not precisely synchronized on every machine in Quartz cluster, load balancing will not work reliably. Most likely the server with the time most in the future will run most if not all the jobs alone.

> why these two apps don't just run the job every minute

I don't understand this question. Do you mean that some jobs aren't run at all (which your log suggests, it misses e.g. `09:48:00`)?

Comment: As to your question, precisely yes. The job didn't fire at 9:48, 9:49, 9:50, 9:52, 9:53, etc.

Comment: @daveslab: Does it work on a single server? Do you observe any misfires in your logs?

Comment: I observe misfires even with two instances on my local machine (just re-tested to make sure)

Comment: I see 11:06, 7, 9, 12, 15, 16

Comment: @daveslab: try increasing `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` (now it's `1` - far too low) - maybe your job runs for too long and no other threads are available?

Comment: @"Tomasz Nurkiewicz" well it only takes 2 seconds to execute, but I'll try increasing the thread count.

Comment: Actually, interestingly enough, I ran one instance with a `threadCount` of 5 and it **still** doesn't run every minute.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. There was a stray process running which was picking up the other times.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, sorry to have wasted your time on such a n00b mistake.